# How to export a copy of a database from phpMyAdmin or MySqlWorkbench for use in VS2017 Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, phpmyadmin, visual-studio-2017, export, mysql-workbench

I'm the lead programmer for Unit Testing at my business and I would like to be able to create a copy of the database that will be accessed to run Unit Tests. I'm told I can export the database from phpMyAdmin or MySqlWorkbench (the later which I don't see an obvious way to export), but I'm not sure how to connect that copy to the Unit Test to reference when testing. If someone could explain the process of going from exporting all the way to how to make the Unit Tests make use of that exported copy, I would be very appreciative. Even if you only know some of the steps in between, that would still be helpful at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Whomever suggested that you export the database was suggesting that you then import it to another server running in a completely independent testing environment. You would configure a MySQL instance as the QA or testing server and, when performing the Unit Testing, point the tests to the test server instead of the production data. How exactly you'd do that depends on the unit test system you're using and your network environment.

A much less robust solution would be to copy the data to a testing database running on the same server. Since it's a different database name, you can safely interact with that instead of the production data. Within phpMyAdmin, there is a copy database feature in the Operations tab. You'd have to modify your tests to connect to the new database name, in this case.